# Possible to rollback from QGIS 2.0.1?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, geojson, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Unfortunately Ubuntu has automatically upgraded my QGIS from 1.8 to 2.0.1. And 2.0.1 which creates GeoJSON files that OpenLayers cannot parse.

Would be best for me to rollback to 1.8, so I can get on with my work for now.

Can anyone help?

thanks

Mini

Comment: That's strange. Can you post a link of Geojson that OpenLayers cannot parse. I haven't seen that happen with QGIS.

Comment: I have used Geojson made from qgis 2.0 with openlayers 2.12, there was no problem.

Comment: The error according to Firebug is: 'JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name'. the failing code is here: http://pauldurkan.se/openlayers/map-app/tree-mapp-jqm-demo.php?lang=sv&file=geojson/varbergs-kyrkan-2013-09.geojson (geojson file is here: http://pauldurkan.se/openlayers/map-app/geojson/varbergs-kyrkan-2013-09.geojson ) If I create the file using QGIS 1.8.0 (Which I still have on Windows) all works as before ...

Comment: I even get an error in QGIS 2.0.1 when it tries to load the GeoJSON file it's created!! - Afraid my error's in Swedish, but it's saying "unrecognized data format/source"

Comment: Now doing this instead: ogr2ogr \
-where "blah blah" \
-f "GeoJSON"  output.geojson \
"PG:dbname=test user=postgres password=XXXXXX" public.trad - that works!!